# ngx quill editor not working while using cdkDrag directive of Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop, ngx-quill

Quill editor not focused or not able to type the content while using cdkDrag directive of Angular Material.

Here I share the StackBlitz code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xalouc

**Understanding**:

- If right click on the editor, It's editable
- Click on any toolbar menu item, It's editable

Kindly suggest to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This issue should be addressed to the creators

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround, try to add separate element with `cdkDragHandle`:

```html
<div cdkDrag>
  <div cdkDragHandle>drag handle</div>
  <quill-editor></quill-editor>
</div>
```

quill-edit will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).